# Machine requirement for hosting a load balancer (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We are planning to migrate an application from AWS cloud to on-prem. For our application, we were using AWS ALB. For on-prem deployment, we are planning to use an Nginx load balancer. But I'm not sure about what configuration is required for hosting the load balancer because in the cloud (AWS) we are not concerning about the machine specs.

What are the criteria for selecting a machine as a load balancer? I mean the RAM, CPU, etc. I'm afraid that if I choose a 4GB machine will that be enough for the load balancer? How can I choose the machine?

Comment: a LB, or reverse proxy, don't need much to perform (haproxy, apache, nginx, ... can run with less than 0.1 CPU and 1G RAM). Now the real question is: how much traffic would you need to serve? Do you want nginx to do some caching? compression? Do you need to deal with websockets or other long-living sessions? ... Best way is to test, starting with something small, try to tune it, and eventually scale it up. I doubt you would ever need 4G RAM for a reverse proxy.